# How to reverse the float.hex() method in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, hex

Is there a way to reverse the `hex()` method of a `float` in Python? For example,

```
n = 1280.03125
n_hex = n.hex() 
print(n_hex)  # result--> 0x1.4002000000000p+10
```

How can I convert `0x1.4002000000000p+10` back to `1280.03125`? I know you can use `int(num, base)` to convert a number to integer but it doesn't support decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `float.fromhex(str)`:

```
>>> float.fromhex("0x1.4002000000000p+10")
1280.03125
```